# Unable to automatically step into server, remote debugging monitor issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services, debugging

I know there are many posts about this issue, but I can't really find what i really need, so if there's one, please close this one and redirect me.

I was given an application for maintenance and occasional functionality develop. So far so good. But now, i need to develop something in a web service the app is using. And I can't step directly into the web service trough debug mode.

It's .NET 2.0 WinForms application. The Web Service is also .NET 2.0, both written in C# so it's not compatibility issue. Both of the applications are in the same solution file, on the same PC. I don't even think i need to have my remote debugger started.

The whole error says this:

> "Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine 'wscc' failed. The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. Please see help for assistance"

I can start the web service alone (when i start it as startup project, or i browse it directly from localhost server). Also the debugging in the WinForm app is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug on a remote machine, you'll need the Remote Debugging Monitor running on it.  I believe you'll need the monitor to match the version of Visual Studio you are trying to debug with.

This link has instructions on how to set it up for different versions of Visual Studio and whether it's x86 or x64:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=vs.90).aspx

However, if the Remote Debugging Monitor is running, I would check to make sure that the firewall is turned off.  (Or configured correctly to allow access to the process)

*Note: from the above link:
"To start the remote tools for the first time, you must have administrative permissions on the remote device to allow the debugger to configure the firewall."